# Blank popup when trying to checkout or export documents in Documentum. Java applet not triggering

Tags: documentum, webtop

Randomly when I go to check out a document in Webtop I get a UCF error.

[image]

Anyone have any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check a few things:

1) Is Java correctly installed? Is the right version of Java installed? (You can check it at http://www.javatester.org/version.html).

2) Try deleting the ucf folder (something like `C:\Documents and Settings\{USERNAME}\Documentum\ucf`), cleaning IE cache and restarting it.

3) Enable (in file `C:\Documents and Settings\{USERNAME}\Documentum\ucf\{MACHINENAME}\shared\config\ucf.client.config.xml`) and then check UCF logs. Also check Webtop app server logs.

Thanks, Kirill

Answer (score 0):

may be you use some kind of load balancing, and your webtop hidden under load-balancer? UCF session not stored in load-balancer, so this session can randomly ping-ponged between servers and loose.